# Java Strange split behavior with | character

Tags: java, regex, split, character

I have a little file that contains some content that I want to split with the "|" character.

When I tried it with any other character (eg. ">"), it worked perfectally fine, but with the "|" character, there were some unexpected outcomes.

---

*The line itself (here with the > character)*
addere>to add>(1)

*Split ">" outcome*
[addere, to add, (1)]

*Split "|" outcome*
[, a, d, d, e, r, e, |, t, o,  , a, d, d, |, (, 1, )]

---

Why is it splitting everything and even ignoring the "|" character in the string itself?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must escape the pipe character with a backslash, because its meaning is special in a regex.  Then you must escape the backslash for Java itself.  Try:

```
text.split("\\|")
```

Comment: Perfect, an answer within half a minute and works absolutely perfect. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Since `|`  is a meta character,It works when you escape that.

```
String[]  array =youString.split("\\|");
```

[oracle docs on the same](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/beyond/names/syntax.html)